# Compilation fails after switching included headers' order for range-v3

Tags: c++, c++17, header-files, range-v3

When I use `views::set_intersection` and `views::transform` together in **range-v3 v0.12.0**, the order of the headers `range/v3/view/set_algorithm.hpp` and `range/v3/view/transform.hpp` matters. If the former header is included first, the code will not compile. The opposite order compiles well.

This is a minimal example: (see also https://godbolt.org/z/nhK1s3xdv for a live demo)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

// this order fails to compile, however, switch the order, it compiles
#include <range/v3/view/set_algorithm.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

int main () {
    std::map<int, int> m1 {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
    std::map<int, int> m2 {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}};
    {
        std::cout << "set_intersection\n";
        auto res = ranges::views::set_intersection(m1, m2);
        for(auto&& p : res) {
            std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
        }
    }

    {
        std::cout << "set_intersection\n";
        auto res = m1 | ranges::views::set_intersection(m2);
        for(auto&& p : res) {
            std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
        }
    }
    {
        std::cout << "set_intersection and pipe\n";
        auto res = ranges::views::set_intersection(m1, m2)
                     | ranges::views::transform(
                        [](auto&& p) { return 0; });
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, the error message is

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'bind_back'
                return make_view_closure(bind_back(set_intersection_base_fn{},
```

for this line

```cpp
auto res = m1 | ranges::views::set_intersection(m2);
```

Which is nothing to do with `views::transform`.

I searched `bind_back`, and it's defined in `meta/meta.hpp`, and it's already included in [`view/set_algorithm.hpp`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/set_algorithm.hpp#L23).

I don't understand where the bug is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With templates inclusion order matters. range-v3 is heavily templated and it's best not to deviate from the documentation on which headers to include. The `bind_back` you found is nested in a namespace `meta`. The `bind_back` you need is defined in [bind_back.hpp](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/97452bb3eb74a73fc86504421a6a27c92bce6b99/include/range/v3/functional/bind_back.hpp#L186C5-L186C27), see [the range-v3 documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/group__group-utility.html#ga73e86fba6a4e39f82aaf0d01b2e9985e).